# Is it required to import a trait whenever it is used?

Tags: rust

I want to be able to have a trait which I can implement multiple times but not need to explicitly import it each time when using the library.

I have a lib.rs file which looks like this:

```
pub mod learning {
    pub mod lin_reg;

    pub trait Model<T,U> {
        fn predict(&self, data:T) -> U;

        fn train(&mut self, data:T, value:U);
    }
}
```

And then I implement this `Model` trait in each of my models (like the Linear Regression model).

Now if the user wants to use the linear regression model they will need to do the following:

```
use ...::learning::lin_reg::LinRegressor;
use ...::learning::Model;

let model = LinRegressor:new();
model.train(...)
```

I want to be able to remove the need to import the `Model` trait each time. Is it possible to do this? Will I need to restructure my library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is *always* required that the end-user has **explicitly** declared that a trait is to be used. You can see examples of this in the standard library, as the `std::io::Read` trait is not available by default and must be used.

You can also follow the IO modules lead here, as it [defines a *prelude*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/prelude/index.html). This is a module called `prelude` which *re-exports* common traits and structs.

There's even a [prelude for the entire standard library](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html). The only difference is that the compiler automatically adds this for you, unless you use the `no_std` feature.

You can do the same for your crate, if you expect that everyone will want to use certain traits if they use it at all.

---

A bit of editorial, but I really prefer this style. As an end-user, I can have a very good sense of what it is that I am importing and relying on. This helps me, the programmer, keep track of my dependencies and make sure that my code isn't gathering "secret" dependencies that ultimately decrease the organization of my code.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I'm a mostly OO programmer by practice and so some of this feels unfamiliar. As I learn more about Rust I'm getting ever more fond of it!

Comment: @user124784 glad to hear it! It was pointed out to me that Rust *is* an OO language, so I'll take the opportunity to point out the same to you. Ultimately it comes down to what the core parts of OO are (for me — message passing and state encapsulation).